# aws lambda cannot call webservice from another vpc

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

we have an aws lambda which is provisioned in a custom vpc subnets.
the lambda makes a call a webservice api call which is another vpc.
however, the call doesn't go thru resulting in object error.

The same lambda works if given on-premise webserive endpoint.
We are able to call web service from browser from ec2 which is the same subnet as lambda  .
it's an HTTPS webservice endpoint. checked the access logs in LB. there are no load balancer access logs for lambda subnet/ip in destination load balancer logs.
but logs are available for ec2 IP address for calls made from the browser.

any settings we need to check for lambda? how does lambda handle certificates for HTTPS?
is there a tracert like a command execute to check where the calls get blocked?

below is lambda code in node js.  with error

```
  use strict;
  
  var soap = require('strong-soap').soap;   
  var aUrl = process.env.a_url;
  var bcUrl = process.env.b_url;

  //aUrl = https://first.second.example.com/test/SoapRecordings/Calculator.asmx?WSDL;
  //bUrl = https://first.second.example.com/Webservice/staging/Service.asmx?WSDL;
  

  var region = process.env.region;
  var secretName = process.env.secretName; 

  var aRequestArgs = {
      UserName: process.env.service_username,
      Password: process.env.service_password
  };
  
  exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {  

       
  var options = {};
  console.log('Calling Service...\n');
  soap.createClient(aUrl, options, function(err, client) {
  
    var method = client['GetLocationData'];
    console.log('called GetLocationData service method\n');
    method(aRequestArgs, function(err, result, envelope, soapHeader) {
      if(err) {
          console.log('error: ' + err);
          return;
      }
      else 
      {

          console.log('Received response from GetLocationData(): \n');
          
          CallService(JSON.stringify(result));
      }
  });

  function CallService(LocData)
  {
     
    var bRequestArgs = {
        UserID: process.env.service_userid,
        Password: process.env.service_password,
        AuthorizationKey: process.env.service_authorizationkey,
        LocationData: LocData
    }; 
     
    console.log('Calling  Service...\n');
    options = {};
    soap.createClient(bUrl, options, function(err, client) {
    
      var service_method = client['UpdateLocationData'];
      console.log('called UpdateLocationData service method\n');
      
      service_method(bRequestArgs, function(err, result, envelope, soapHeader) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(' error: ' + err);
            return;
        }
        else 
        {
            console.log(' Response: \n' + JSON.stringify(result));
                            
        }
    });  
    });
     
  }
  
  });

 }; //exports.handler
  '''


error exception here :TLSSocket.socketErrorListener


'''
{"errorType":"TypeError","errorMessage":"Cannot read property 'GetRFCLocationData' of undefined","stack":["TypeError: Cannot read property 'GetLocationData' of undefined","    at /var/task/index.js:35:24","    at /var/task/node_modules/strong-soap/src/soap.js:54:5","    at /var/task/node_modules/strong-soap/src/soap.js:36:16","    at /var/task/node_modules/strong-soap/src/parser/wsdl.js:480:13","    at Request._callback (/var/task/node_modules/strong-soap/src/http.js:166:18)","    at self.callback (/var/task/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)","    at Request.emit (events.js:375:28)","    at Request.onRequestError (/var/task/node_modules/request/request.js:877:8)","    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:375:28)","    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:475:9)"]}
END RequestId: b315720f-2294-449d-8337-35d9226b6615
```

Comment: "resulting in object error" - what is the error message?

Comment: How are the two VPCs connected? How does the traffic get to the other network?

Comment: @Marcin . the error its not able read object of client . looks like no response from webservice .                                             
                 {"errorType":"TypeError","errorMessage":"Cannot read property 'GetRLocationData' of undefined","stack":["TypeError: Cannot read property (events.js:375:28)","    at Request.onRequestError (/var/task/node_modules/request/request.js:877:8)","    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:375:28)","    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:475:9)"]}
END RequestId: b315720f-2294-449d-8337-35d9226b6615

Comment: @JohnRotenstein we have transit gateway connecting two VPCs.

Comment: The url `https://first.second.example.com` seems to be public one, not private? Can you confirm that it does not use internet? Or it should be public, or private?

Comment: @Marcin . the issue is resolved. it seems that lambda nodejs doesn't have a certificate to decrypt https call . we added the process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = 0 in nodejs . it started working. but the strange thing which made us not to think in that direction was our on-prem webservice was working which was HTTPS too.!!  now need to see how to package nodejs bundle with certificate. Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out. You can make an answer to your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

the issue is resolved. it seems that lambda nodejs doesn't have a certificate to decrypt HTTPS call. we added the process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = 0 in nodejs . it started working.